# How to make animation work in Xcode 5 iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, core-animation

I have an old app developed for ios6 and I want to publish it by using Xcode 5 for iOS 7 everything works fine except my animations.It was working before but not now so any idea to fix it ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    self.showimage.image = self.sendimage;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:18.0
                     animations:^{ _moveme.Center = CGPointMake(160.0f,520.0f); }
     ] ;

}
```

I have checked some tutorials and a similar question but I couldt fine a solution.

Problem solved when I use this.

```
    - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:18.0
                     animations:^{ _moveme.Center = CGPointMake(160.0f,520.0f); }
     ] ; 
}
```

Comment: you may want to put that animation not into the `–viewDidLoad` but a subsequent stage of the view lifecycle, e.g. `–viewDidAppear:` or later, when the view is already in the navigation stack.

Comment: But I want my animation to start when view is loaded when I put inside the viewdidapper it doesn't start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation code is correct and should work fine.
The issue is, that you call it in `-viewDidLoad` which is to early to commit an animation.

After `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` it is *save** to change the frame/center.
But i would recommend to call it in `-viewDidAppear` which is called right after your view appears (every time).

Comment: after a long conversion in chat problem solved by using viewDidLayoutSubView

Answer (score 2):

The animation code looks correct. But having it in viewDidLoad doesn't guarantee that you'll actually see the animation on the screen. I suggest that you move the animation code from `viewDidLoad` and into `viewDidAppear:`, or some other method where you know that your view is already visible.

Comment: But I want my animation to start when view is loaded when I put inside the viewdidapper it doesn't start –

Comment: If that is true, you handle the displaying wrong. How do you add the `viewController` to your navigation stack?

Comment: I dont understand your question but let say this before Xcode 5 this code was %100 working the animation always played after view was loaded.

Comment: How do you display the `viewController`? There has be a lot of changes between 6 and 7 regarding `viewController`handling.

Comment: How do I display it ? Its in a storyboard its displayed on it own.

Comment: So you display it by a push segue, or modally, or embed in a container?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55674/discussion-between-yinkou-and-bugra-sezer).

Comment: with a modal segue which also carriers an image from the previous storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:18.0
                                 delay:0
                                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                                 animations:^{
                                     _moveme.Center = CGPointMake(160.0f,520.0f);
                                 }
                                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration: 18
                              delay: 0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{

                         _moveme.Center = CGPointMake(160.0f,520.0f);

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Comment: Not working same result with my old code the png file which I try to move gets disappeared from the scene.